# Seeking Validation for Stepper Motor Control PCB Design

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, arduino, circuit-analysis, pcb-design

I'm currently in the process of developing a PCB intended as a base board for the precise control of a stepper motor. The system involves an LCD display and various sensors for control. Before proceeding with the PCB fabrication, I'd greatly appreciate your expertise in validating my design.

Key components used in the design:

Microcontroller: Atmega 2560
Power Supply: Hi-link 20M12 switching power supply, providing 12V and 1.6A
Voltage Regulation: LM2596 step-down converter to reduce voltage to 7V
Linear Regulators: LM7805 - one dedicated to the microcontroller, the other for peripheral components
Real-Time Clock: DS3231
Stepper Motor Driver: TMC2209

I've taken the following steps in my design:

Implemented five 100nF decoupling capacitors, one for each 5V pin on the microcontroller, placed as close to the microcontroller as possible.
Utilized additional decoupling capacitors on the regulators.
I designed this PCB in EasyEDA and will use the copper GND area of the entire board except for the area around the AC pins to avoid shorting in that area.

I'm seeking input on the following aspects of my design:

The utilization of two separate LM7805 regulators, one for the microcontroller and another for the peripheral components. Do you believe this separation is necessary or beneficial?
The use of a slot in the PCB for decoupling AC voltage from the rest of the circuit.
I would greatly appreciate any feedback or insights you can provide. If you identify any other potential errors or areas for improvement in the circuit, please don't hesitate to share your knowledge.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome! For future reference, please draw all negative and ground connections pointing down, positive up. Don’t cross though symbols with wires. What’s the max speed (clock or PWM) the board will see?

Comment: The maximum clock speed of the board is 16 MHz

Comment: I wouldn’t do anything at that speed without a ground plane. I’m not saying it impossible, but very challenging.

Comment: This is 2 layers only?

Comment: Yes, it is two layer PCB

Comment: I think I wrote it above. I will be using a copper ground area on both sides of the board. I didn't use it in the given picture to make it easier to see the individual connections of the components. I will use ground plane on the entire board except for the area around the AC pins to avoid shorting in this area.

Comment: You have no room for a valid groundplane. Currently one critical issue with your pcb is the size of the power conductors. You have not considered the inductance and resistance of these tracks. There seems to be mains voltages onthe pcb as well. If this is the case, you have inadequate clearances. This makes your pcb extremely dangerous.

Comment: Ok so I need to move the converter and LDO closer to the power supply to reduce the inductance of the power tracks and also widen them to reduce resistance. And make bigger clearences between main AC power lines on pcb. Do I understand that well?

Comment: I’d suggest you remove any mains from your pcb. Currently the mains is too close to the other wiring and needs a significant redesign to resolve that issue. No need to move the converter or LDO, but you do need to pay attention to the layout and track thicknesses. Why in this day and age would you use an AVR2560 - that’s retro computing. There’s so many cheaper and better solutions.

Comment: unfortunately, I cannot remove the mains from this board because I need power for the power source. Is it explained somewhere how these tracks should be isolated from the others on the pcb?

Comment: You're right that using an AVR2560 nowadays is a bit retro computing but I was used to working with arduino boards so this chip was what I thought of when I needed more pins. But when I saw the price of this chip compared to the others, I was a bit taken aback. I was thinking of replacing it with an ESP32, what do you think? I wanted to change it before, I was just too lazy to redo it, but now when I see that I will have to redesign it, I will probably change it.

Comment: @Kabl62 - Hi, Unfortunately you misunderstood the site :( You posted an "answer" (look above the text box you used - it says "Your Answer") but it wasn't an answer to your question. I could have added it to the bottom of your question as an update *but* then it would mean people have to read all your original question *and* all the changes in your update. That's unreasonable. So much has changed that the best option is for you to delete this question and write a new question about your new design. || IMHO this is why design review questions are a poor fit for the site, as the goalposts move :(